# Why didn't they just use Ironclad Beetles hybrid fighters, or at least one of them, to deal with the roaches in Terra Formars?

Tags: anime, manga, terra-formars

I mean I understand having all the cast use this power would be OP in terms of durability, making for a bad story, but having at least one fighter with this ability would be so helpful in dealing with the *Terra Formars*.

Like if the Ironclad Beetle needs a drill to stick a pin in them, AND they can get run over by a car and be pretty much fine, then they pretty much have a weak Superman on their side. Like no way in Hades are the roaches killing them without really good weaponry.

Comment: Are you primarily asking about the manga, the anime, or both?

Comment: @LogicDictates both.